# Fill empty dates in array of dates in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in codeigniter like below. As shown below, there are some spaces between dates. After 1st April, there is 3rd and after that its 10th and so on.

```
 Array
    (
        [2019-04-01] => 1
        [2019-04-03] => 3
        [2019-04-10] => 8
        [2019-04-15] => 1
    )
```

I need those empty dates to be there with a value `'0'` so at last, the array will look like:

```
    Array
            (
       [2019-04-01] => 1
       [2019-04-02] => 0
       [2019-04-03] => 3
       [2019-04-04] => 0
       [2019-04-05] => 0
       [2019-04-06] => 0
       [2019-04-07] => 0
       [2019-04-08] => 0
       [2019-04-09] => 0
       [2019-04-10] => 8
       [2019-04-11] => 0
       [2019-04-12] => 0
       [2019-04-13] => 0
       [2019-04-14] => 0
       [2019-04-15] => 1
            )
```

The first and last `index` of array will work as range.

**What I've tried so far**
I was using this approach but this doesn't seem to work. In below code, `testArr` is the array posted above

```
                $i=0;    
                foreach ($testArr as $key => $value) {

                if($i==count($testArr)-1){break;}

                $currentDay=new DateTime($key);
                $nextDay=new DateTime(array_keys($testArr)[$i]);


                $diff=date_diff($nextDay,$currentDay);
                $diffint=intval($diff->format("%a"));
                if($diffint!==1){
                    $currentDay->modify('+1 day');
                    $temp=array($currentDay->format('Y-m-d')=>0);
                    $testArr = $this->insertArrayAtPosition($testArr,$temp,$i);
                }

                $i++;
            }
```

If this question already has answers somewhere, then don't forget to mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DatePeriod` to get the range between the first key and the last key of the array.

```
$arr = array(
    "2019-04-01" => 1,
    "2019-04-03" => 3,
    "2019-04-10" => 8,
    "2019-04-15" => 1,
);

$keys = array_keys( $arr );
$start = new DateTime($keys[0]);
$stop = new DateTime($keys[ count( $keys ) - 1 ]);
$stop->modify('+1 day');

$range = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $stop);
$result = array();

foreach ($range as $key => $value) {
    $date = $value->format('Y-m-d');

    if ( isset( $arr[ $date ] ) ) $result[ $date ] = $arr[ $date ];
    else $result[ $date ] = 0;
}
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [2019-04-01] => 1
    [2019-04-02] => 0
    [2019-04-03] => 3
    [2019-04-04] => 0
    [2019-04-05] => 0
    [2019-04-06] => 0
    [2019-04-07] => 0
    [2019-04-08] => 0
    [2019-04-09] => 0
    [2019-04-10] => 8
    [2019-04-11] => 0
    [2019-04-12] => 0
    [2019-04-13] => 0
    [2019-04-14] => 0
    [2019-04-15] => 1
)
```

Comment: Working perfect Eddie ! :) Thanks for helping me out. Appreciated

Comment: Just a little question for my personal knowledge, whats the reason for the modification of +1 day? :) You added 1 more day in the range but still its working perfect. Is the last index exclusive from the range?

Comment: without the `+1` It will end on `2019-04-14`. It is range between the start and end so to include the 15, we need to add +1

Answer (score 5):

You can use [DatePeriod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) to generate every date within your target period and fill the values for each from your set.

```php
$values = ['2019-04-01' => 10, '2019-04-02' => 20, '2019-04-04' => 30];

$dates = new DatePeriod(new DateTime('2019-04-01'), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime('2019-04-04'));

foreach($dates as $date) {
    $values[$date->format('Y-m-d')] = $values[$date->format('Y-m-d')] ?? 0;
}
```

Resulting in:

```php
$values = [
    '2019-04-01' => 10,
    '2019-04-02' => 20,
    '2019-04-03' => 0,
    '2019-04-04' => 30,
];
```

Comment: Its working fine. Its adding the dates but its messing up the order of the dates. The starting 4 index are there which were initially in the array but the filled elements are pushed at the end. Any way to put them on correct position?

Comment: @MuhammadOsama `YYYY-MM-DD` dates are easy to sort, you can use `ksort($values)`.

Comment: Thanks Sam :) I appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `DatePeriod` please check below code.

```
<?php
$testArr = array('2019-04-01'=>1,'2019-04-03'=>3,'2019-04-10'=>8,'2019-04-15'=>1);

$start = new DateTime('2019-04-01'); // your start key
$end = new DateTime('2019-04-16'); // your end key

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$finalArr = array();
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    if(array_key_exists($dt->format("Y-m-d"), $testArr)){
        $finalArr[$dt->format("Y-m-d")] = $testArr[$dt->format("Y-m-d")];
    }else{
        $finalArr[$dt->format("Y-m-d")] =  0;   
    }

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($finalArr);
exit();
?>
```